Numerical Example of Dimension of a Variety
I am studying the dimension of variety and so far have not been able to find a concrete numerical example... So, I'm trying to come up with some fairly simple numerical example of the following statement regarding the dimension of variety.

If $Y \subset X$ is a closed subvariety, then it indeed holds that $\dim(Y) \leq \dim(X)$, and typically $\dim(Y) < \dim(X)$ unless $Y = X$.

Can anyone tell me if my example is correct?
Def: Dimension
The dimension of a variety $X$, denoted $\dim(X)$, is the maximum length of chains of distinct subvarieties within $X$.
Example
The subvarieties of $ Z(y - x) \subset \mathbb{A}^2 $ are:

$ Z(y - x) $ itself (the whole line).
$ Z(x - a, y - a) $ for each $ a \in k $ (points on the line).

Thus, dim $ Z(y - x) = 1 $ as a subvariety of $ \mathbb{A}^2 (= Z(0)) $ and dim $ Z(x - a, y - a) = 0 $ as points in $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Yes, your example is correct.  The variety $Z(y - x)$ is isomorphic to the affine line $\mathbb A^1$, which is one-dimensional because its closed, irreducible proper subsets are (zero-dimensional) points.
There are different definitions of variety used by different textbooks.  Classically, a variety is required to be, among other things, an irreducible topological space of finite dimension.  If this is the definition you're taking, then yes, if $Y$ is a proper closed subset of a (by definition, irreducible) variety $X$, then the dimension of $Y$ is strictly less than the dimension of $X$.
If you don't require $X$ to be irreducible, then this is false.  For example, you can take $X$ to be the disjoint union $Y \cup Y$ of two irreducible varieties $Y$, and then $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension.

Got it! Thanks!
